# Not able to write on a file

Tags: java

The above is a working code snippet. The code runs fine but it does not write what is inside the `else if(line.contains("{NEW_LIMIT}"))` statement.

Another problem is that after the program writes into a new text file it loses its original format, as in to say it just writes everything in a single line.
Is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
public static void replace1(String name, String limit, String nlimit) throws IOException
{
    File infile = new File("s://BlackBuck/Question_1_Template.txt");
    File outfile = fileReturn();

    FileWriter fw;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;

    FileReader fr;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    String line, putdata = null;;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(infile);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        fw = new FileWriter(outfile);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if(line != null)
            {   
                if(line.contains("{CUSTOMER_NAME}"))
                {
                    putdata = line.replace("{CUSTOMER_NAME}", name);
                    bw.write(putdata);
                }
                else if(line.contains("{CURRENT_LIMIT}"))
                {
                    putdata = line.replace("{CURRENT_LIMIT}", limit);
                    bw.write(putdata);
                }
                else if(line.contains("{NEW_LIMIT}"))
                {
                    putdata = line.replace("{NEW_LIMIT}", nlimit);
                    bw.write(putdata);
                }
                else
                {
                    bw.write(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }finally {
        bw.close();
        br.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you use the old outdated File API instead of the modern NIO (`Files`, `Path`, `Paths`)?

Comment: @Zabuza no reasons, I thought buffered streams would be better approach and i wan't aware that it's an outdated API. Next time i will keep that in mind.

Comment: readLine() doesn't return the newline. So you have to write one explicitly. That will solve the "all one line problem".

Comment: To add a new line call the method bw.newLine().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a line contains `{CUSTOMER_NAME}` or `{CURRENT_LIMIT}`, then statements `{NEW_LIMIT}` won't be run. You can simply fix this using following codes:

```
if(line != null) {
    putdata = line.replace("{CUSTOMER_NAME}", name)
            .replace("{CURRENT_LIMIT}", limit)
            .replace("{NEW_LIMIT}", nlimit);
    bw.write(putdata);
    // append a line separator to current line
    bw.newLine();
}
```